# Issues creating a job in GCP ML Engine using Gcloud command

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-ml

GCP ML Engine source directory issue-
I have built an image classification model which I want to train in the cloud using GCP ML Engine. However when I try to create a job using the below command in CLI, I get an error-

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
    --package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
    --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
    --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
    --region $REGION \
    --config config.yaml \
```

I am getting error-

> Source directory is not a valid directory

although I configured the `Trainer_package_path`, `Main_trainer_module` and `Job_dir` to google cloud bucket.
Is there any other prerequisite that I am missing?

Comment: What OS are you running on? I would run `echo` on all your variables to ensure that they are all set

Comment: @ScottMcC I am running it in Google Shell from inside the storage bucket. I am doing the echo right now

Comment: What do you mean you configured the `$MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE` to google cloud bucket? This needs to point to a .py file (see for example the [census](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census) sample). Also, have you ran the `echo` indeed? If so, have you made sure that the variables are in accordance to the descriptions given in [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ml-engine/jobs/submit/training)?

Comment: I am doing the following- MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE="gs://<bucket_name>/<direcotry>/<model_file_name.py> and then executing the gcloud command.. It keeps returning the error- "Source directory is not a valid directory". Yes, I echoed each of them, they look fine.

Answer (score 0):

The module name refers to the Python file within the package. Don't use an absolute path.

The package path needs to be local, I think.

See information about Python packaging at:

http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

Comment: Thanks @Lak. Right now my trainer package has-  __init__.py and my model.py file.  I am referring to this while executing the google ml-engine training job

Comment: And the package path is local and not in GCS...?